# URL gets changed on browser refresh ($routeProvider is used for client side routing)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular-routing, route-provider

I am using Angular for client and Nodejs (Express) for server side to build single page application. To support browser history for different view, I am using $routeProvider. It works well if I don't refresh the browser. But whenever I refresh the browser I notice that URL is changed which caused issue as that URL pattern doesn't exist at server. Following are more details.

Angular js router code:

```
 $routeProvider.
                when('/categoryview', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/partials/app/categoryview/CategoryView.html',
                    controller: 'ApplicationController'
                }).
                when('/:categoryId/themes', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/partials/app/themeview/ThemeView.html',
                    controller: 'ThemeViewController'
                })
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/categoryview'});
```

**URL in browser as application launched first time:** `http://localhost:3000/themelibrary#/categoryview`

**URL in browser on refresh:** `http://localhost:3000/categoryview#/categoryview`

If you notice then you will found that the root URL **"/themelibrary"** is changed into **"/categoryview"** which caused issue as "/categoryview" is not supported by server. I also tried different version of Angularjs but not success.

Please help and let me know if need more code to explain this problem.

**Edit:** Added Nodejs router details
**UI Routes:**

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    // route for home page
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {      
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
    //Route for login to present the login page back to user
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {       
        res.set({'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})
        res.render('login.ejs', {message: req.flash('loginMessage')})
    });

 //Route to get the username and password and authenticate
    app.post('/authenticate', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/themelibrary', // redirect to the secure themelibrary section
        failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
    }));

     // route for default lending page
    app.get('/themelibrary', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {       
        var url= require('url');
        console.log("themelibrary hash url >> " + url.hash);
        res.charset = 'utf8';
        res.set({'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            user: req.user
                    // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {    
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

**API Routes:**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/users/:id', userService.getUserById);
    app.get('/users', userService.getAllUsers);
    app.post('/themes', themeService.addTheme);
    app.get('/themes/:id', themeService.getThemeById);
    app.put('/themes/:id', themeService.updateTheme);   
    app.delete('/themes/:id', themeService.deleteTheme);
    app.get('/themes', themeService.getThemes); 
    app.get('/resources/:code', languageResourceService.getLanguageResourceByCode); 
    app.get('/config', applicationConfigService.getApplicationConfig);  
    app.post('/keepalive', applicationConfigService.keepAlive); 
    app.get('/categories', categoryService.getAllCategories);
};
```

Comment: You'll avoid this problem if you turn off html5 mode which means all your urls will be like localhost:3000/#/categoryview/ instead of localhost:3000/categoryview. If you stick with html5mode you'll have to read this: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode

Comment: I don't want to use html5 mode. That's why I did not set it "true". By default is "false" so I think I am good on this part.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your express routing rules to give a full answer, but since themelibrary is not a valid route according to the $routeProvider, your `otherwise` rule is being activated if you browse to this from within your application.

If you refresh the browser at this URL, $routeProvider is bypassed and the request is sent directly to your node.js instance where express will handle the route.

As for the hash route, that all depends if you have html5mode enabled or not as @david-spence pointed out.

### Edit

The penny finally dropped on this one.  If your angular app has loaded (and the only way for it to load is via the `/themelibrary` path), it will take over all of your routing, so any route changes via the application will be handled by `ngRoute`.  That is to say, *there will be no page reloads*.  Therefore, if the backend server is being hit by a request to `/categoryview`, some other part of the application is requesting a full page redirect via `window.location.href` or something similar.

In short, your routes are fine, some other part of the application is bypassing your routes and going straight back to the server (which it shouldn't).

Comment: Thanks...added nodejs router details. Please note; I don't want to use html5mode therefore I have not set to "true" which I think is fine.

Comment: The only way I can replicate this behaviour is when `html5Mode` is set to `true`.  Perhaps try explicitly setting html5Mode to false.  Also, what version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: I tried using html5Mode to false but still same issue. I am using 1.3.0-beta.5 however I tried old version as well, but no success.

Comment: Did you manage to track down any other redirects in your code (see edit)?

Comment: I was trying to look into root cause in last few days however couldn't figure out the root cause. Whenever I was reading your suggestion then I always think that issue is not at the angular client but some where the way I am using nodejs routing. Still I coudn't figure out the root cause. Then I thought to use html5Mode(true) and changed the server and client code. Now its working fine. Not sure what was the exact issue in html5Mode(false) approach. Thanks for sharing insight on probable root cause.